# ASP.NET Core Deployment Requirements

Tags: server, operating-system, asp.net-core-2.0, load-balancing

One of our client wants us to develop & deploy an ASP.NET Core web application. His requirements are as follows-

1. Develop an ASP.NET Core web application
2. Primary Server Hardware & Software Installation
3. Backup Server Hardware & Software Installation
4. Load Balancer Installation

Project with such requirements is rather new for us. What I would like to know, is to figure out the best combination of deployment environment in terms of -

```
- Server OS (Windows is not allowed)
- Web Server 
- Load Balancer
- Any other related software/s.
```

May I get an expert opinion?

Thanks.